# I'm using SUBSTRING to isolate the text "AUG" from a flat file record. How can I convert that to "08"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am using SSIS to create a data flow that imports a flat file into a database table. One of the transformations that needs to be done is to convert the date in the flat file which is formatted like "30AUG2013" to a datetime datatype format that can be written into the table. I believe this format would be 2013-08-30.

I am currently using an expression in the Derived Column Transformation editor to move the "30" to the end and move the "2013 to the beginning using SUBSTRING and RIGHT functions. I am having problems however, changing the AUG to 08 (keep in mind the solution would need to handle all months, not just August). Is there any way to do this within the expression editor? This is what I have so far.

```
(RIGHT(Service_Date,4)) + "-" + (SUBSTRING(Service_Date,3,3)) + "-" + (SUBSTRING(Service_Date,1,2))
```

So currently that would return: 2013-AUG-30

How can I change that AUG to 08 (or APR to 04, MAR to 03, etc)?

Also, once I get that into the format "2013-08-30" I should be able to just add the DT_DATE Type cast function in front of it in the expression to be able to successfully import it right?

Thank you in advance for any help, suggestions, tips, etc that you can provide. It is all greatly appreciated.

EDIT: SO, I definitely was over thinking this problem. The solution is as simple as this:

```
(DT_DBDATE)(SUBSTRING(Service_Date,1,2)+ "-" +(SUBSTRING(Service_Date,3,3)+ "-" +(SUBSTRING(Service_Date,6,4))
```

This expression just formats the date from 30AUG2013 to 30-AUG-2013 and the DT_DBDATE type cast can convert it to the datetime sql server data type. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If your objective is to format the date: 30AUG2013 to 2013-08-30, you may want to try an expression like this

```
select CAST ('30AUG2013' as date)
```

This returns

```
2013-08-30
```

Comment: This seems like the best way to go about this but I can't seem to get it to work. Admittedly, I'm quite inexperienced working within SSIS. Where should this expression go exactly? I'm currently trying it in the Derived Column Transformation editor under the expression field for the date column I'm working with. When I put it there, the editor doesn't accept it and it stays red. Thanks for the response.

Comment: I did not use SSIS before in fact, however, this expression is valid column function in SQL Server. Assuming that you are trying to apply it on the data retrieved from  a database column, I expect that you'd be able to edit the SQL to do something like SELECT col1,col2, CAST(Col3 as Date), col4 FROM myTable. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not scared of a little .net, use a script component:

```
Dim dateConvert As Date = DateTime.Parse("30AUG2013")
```